# How to negative a row of a list in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to make a list negative among the lists of list

I tried this

```
X=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
X[0]=-X[0]
```

But it produces error
I want the output as

```
X=[[-1,-2,-3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: X[0]=[x*-1 for x in X[0]]  --  [edited per luk's comment]

Comment: @ThomasKimber you could also do `[-x for x in X[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the elements and multiply them with -1.

- You cant use `-X[0]` because that is not proper python syntax for a list object
- You can't use `X[0]*-1` because that is a list and `*` operator doesn't do elementwise multiplication for a list object.

```
X=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

X[0] = [-1*i for i in X[0]]
X
```

```
[[-1, -2, -3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
X[0] = [-n for n in X[0]]
```

Or numpy if you want to multiply arrays by a number:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
X[0] = -X[0]
```